# replace strings inside a substring

Tags: string

I have this string:
"*The quick brown f0x jumps 0ver the lazy d0g, the quick brown f0x jumps 0ver the lazy d0g.*".

I need a function that will replace all **zeros** between "**brown**" and "**lazy**" with "**o**". So the output will look like this:
"*The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy d0g, the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy d0g.*".
So it will look *all over* the string and most importantly will leave all other zeros intact.

```
function(text, leftBorder, rightBorder, searchString, replaceString) : string;
```

Is there any good algorithm?

Comment: It might be helpful for you to mention the programming language that you are using for this because some APIs come with specific classes that can handle Strings in different ways, resulting in slightly different algorithms or implementations.

Comment: what is leftborder and rightborder? positions inside the string?

Comment: akonsu, no they are strings to find. Luis, well I can understand many languages, so it can be any language you want as long as one can see an underlying algorithm by looking at code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Python, here's an example using just string manipulation, eg `split()`, `indexing` etc. Your programming language should have these features as well.

```
>>> s="The quick brown f0x jumps 0ver the lazy d0g, the quick brown f0x jumps 0ver the lazy d0g."
>>> words = s.split("lazy")
>>> for n,word in enumerate(words):
...     if "brown" in word:
...         w = word.split("brown")
...         w[-1]=w[-1].replace("0","o")
...         word = 'brown'.join(w)
...     words[n]=word
...
>>> 'lazy'.join(words)
'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy d0g, the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy d0g.'
>>>
```

The steps:

1. Split the words on "lazy" to an array A
2. Go through each element in A to look for "brown"
3. if found , split on "brown" into array B. The part you are going to change is the
   last element
4. replace it with whatever methods your programming language provides
5. join back the array B using "brown"
6. update this element in the first array A
7. lastly, join the whole string back using "lazy"

Comment: Ghost Dog, power and equality.